# How to add html document using crawler symfony2?

Tags: symfony, functional-testing, web-crawler

```
<select id="dealer_information_city" name="dealer_information[city]" required="required"><option value="" disabled="disabled">Choose a city.</option>
<option value="23">California</option>
<option value="114" selected="selected">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
```

Here's my code i want to add a new option using crawler symfony but nothing happen anyone can help me thanks!

```
var_dump($crawler->filter('#used_car_step1_car_model')->addHtmlDocument('<option value="1">New Jersey</option>'));
```